# Using interact from ipywidgets with a dataframe

Tags: python, ipython, ipywidgets

i am new to `ipywidgets` and trying to use the `interact`from this library in combination with a dataframe. My dataframe is:

```
df
KundenNR    Kundengruppe    Wertpapierart   Erlös   Kosten A    Kosten B
1   1   A   100     30  10
1   1   B   200     30  15
1   1   C   300     30  20
```

As far I did the following:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets, interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
from IPython.display import display
def f(x):
    df1 = df.copy()
    df1['Kosten A'] = x
    y = x*x
    print(df1, y)

interact(f, x=(10,50,5))
```

Which succesfully gives me the desired outcome, which means that I see the datframe and the column `Kosten A` is changed with the interaction button:
[image]

I really wonder how can I pass the dataframe directly to the function, instead creating a copy out of it. Is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the dataframe as an argument to the function wrapped with `fixed`. You should be able to call your dataframe afterwards and any changes due to your interact should be permanent.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from ipywidgets import widgets, interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
    from IPython.display import display

    df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])

    def f(x, df):
        df
        df['Kosten A'] = x
        y = x*x
        print(df, y)

    interact(f, x=(10,50,5), df = fixed(df))
```

Comment: This leaves df modified. `fixed` just means, it is passed to the interacted function 'as is'. I'll write a different answer to handle the OP's  case.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fixed` pseudo-widget is a way of passing extra arguments to the interacted function, which are not displayed as widgets. See: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Fixing-arguments-using-fixed

However, the implementation of `fixed` is very simple (`interaction.py`):

```
from traitlets import HasTraits, Any, Unicode

class fixed(HasTraits):
    """A pseudo-widget whose value is fixed and never synced to the client."""
    value = Any(help="Any Python object")
    description = Unicode('', help="Any Python object")
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        super(fixed, self).__init__(value=value, **kwargs)
    def get_interact_value(self):
        """Return the value for this widget which should be passed to
        interactive functions. Custom widgets can change this method
        to process the raw value ``self.value``.
        """
        return self.value
```

Thus, you can write your own pseudo-widget, `fixed_copy`:

```
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact, fixed

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])

class fixed_copy(fixed):
    def get_interact_value(self):
        return self.value.copy()

@interact(x=(10, 50, 5), df=fixed_copy(df))
def f(x, df):
    df['Kosten A'] = x
    y = x*x
    return (df, y)
```

it shows the modified `df` nicely, but after that, the value of `df` is still:

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```